# Switch case environment that provides different kinds of braces for an equation

Tags: amsmath, ifthenelse

I'm trying to create a shortcut for equations inside braces. Specifically, I'd like to create a command that works like this:

input:

```
\strongbraces{my particular expression} %basically the default option
\strongbraces[s]{my particular expression}
\strongbraces[m]{my particular expression}
\strongbraces[l]{my particular expression}
```

output:

```
 \left( my particular expression \right)
 \bigl( my particular expression \bigr)
 \Bigl( my particular expression \Bigr)
 \biggl( my particular expression \biggr)
```

I've tryed working with switch case options but I think I haven't comprehended how it works

edit:
Thanks for the response, I had tried using it but it wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but that's really close! Sorry for not providing my wip, here's what I've tryed so far:

```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage{amsmath}
> \usepackage{xifthen}
> \usepackage{xstring} 
> \usepackage{tikz, mathtools}
> \usepackage{mathtools}
> 
> \newcommand{\strongbraces}[2]{ \IfStrEqCase \ifthenelse{      
> {\equal{s}{#1}}{\bigl( #2\bigr)} %if I put the first argument as 's'
> %then I'll have my second argument inside (these braces) 
> {\equal{m}{#1}}{\Bigl( #2\Bigr)} %if I put the first argument as 'm'
> %then I'll have my second argument inside bigger ()
> {\equal{#1}{l}}{\biggl( #2\biggr)} %and so on... 
> {\equal{#1}{X}}{\Biggl( #2\Biggr)} {\left #2\right}}}     
>   \begin{document}        % unfortunatelly it doesn't recognize my first argument
> \[\strongbraces{s}{expression} \]
> 
>       \end{document}
```

I'd like to use

> \strongbraces[s]{my expression}

> \strongbraces{my expression}

for these outputs

> \bigl( my expression \bigr)

> (my expression)

but with this code I have to use {arg1}{arg2} and I don't like that :(

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the TeX code you tried so far ...

Comment: You can use `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: In the end I don't think this is a good idea from the LaTeX side, your code will be very hard to read later on. It might be better as a template in your editor.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the format for delimiters defined by `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\strongbraces}{\{}{\}}

\begin{document}

$\strongbraces{a+b=c}$

$\strongbraces[\big]{a+b=c}$

$\strongbraces[\Bigg]{a+b=c}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remember the starred version. And it might be a good idea to note that we do nt recommend using `\left...\right` as the default (as the OP mentions in the question).